# Is calling su binary limited by permissions declared in the manifest

Tags: android, permissions, su, root

I know that su request essentially changes the uid of the process so it gets new pid (0 ) and can access all resources. 
But what I don't get is, does this effectively disable the permission system in android since it's dependent on kernel filtering access based on pid and uid?
For example if I request root and allow it (when super-user apk shows the dialog) since this elevates access for my process (giving it open door to access any resource it wants) can I then use internet for example without the internet permission in the manifest since that resource is available to uid 0 at the kernel level?

I know that doing thing like this would not be welcomed by users and am asking this because I just want to find out about permission system on android and this was the use case I didn't fully understand.

EDIT: It turns out that I was wrong about the process uid switching, I thought that su will just change uid of DalvikVM instance executing the apk and thus give it elevated permissions. Actually it turns out that requesting root starts a new process with another uid (and permissions) that communicates with the apk process. Big thanks to Chris Stratton for pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: I noticed there is one close request. Could initiator please elaborate why the question should be closed? I think the question is explained in detail and it has it's place on stack-overflow, I also searched for similar questions and couldn't find one that explains this but I might have missed some answers so if that is the case please provide link to possible duplicate.

Comment: The key issue is that `su` does not change the uid ID of a process; rather it (potentially) allows you to launch an independent process as a different uid.  If that uid is root, then your independent process would gain all of the small handful of kernel-enforced permissions, for example to the network and file system.  But it will find it extremely difficult to use most ordinary Android-framework resources as being independent it won't even be registered with the Android IPC system used to implement them.

Comment: Hm so it basically starts a new process and that process has root permissions but cannot communicate with the android apk that spawned it?

Comment: It can communicate with the app process by many means - pipes, sockets, etc.  But it will have difficulty obtaining many android-level platform services on its own.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I will edit my question to fix the things I guessed wrong, but to be honest your comments are good as an answer on their own too. So exualy I am right about that the new process has access to network resources and is not limited by permissions but as you explained it's hard to communicate and use that resource from the apk.